# How to merge groups of touching lines to multilinestring

Tags: r, sf

I would like to join groups of lines into multilinestrings if they touch. In the plot below, I should get two objects of `sf` class `MULTILINESTRING` from the 6 lines. What is an easy way of doing this (when having 2 mio lines)? Is there maybe a pre-defined command that let's one do this?

[image]

data:

```
library(sf)
lines <- st_sfc(list(st_linestring(rbind(c(0,0), c(0.5, 0.7))), 
                 st_linestring(rbind(c(0.5, 0.7), c(1, 1))), 
                 st_linestring(rbind(c(2,0), c(1,1))), 
                 st_linestring(rbind(c(1,1), c(1, 3))),
                 st_linestring(rbind(c(3,2), c(4,2))),
                 st_linestring(rbind(c(3,2), c(5,3)))))
```

I tried the following

```
library(igraph)
components(graph.adjlist(st_touches(lines)))
```

`graph.adjlist` transforms the list of elements that touch each other to a graph object and the function `components` identifies the components of each cluster.

But is there a way to do connect the multiple `LINESTRING` into `MULTILINESTRING` if they touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tapply` over the groups defined by the connectivity to make multilinestrings:

```
> com = components(graph.adjlist(st_touches(lines)))

> mlines = do.call(st_sfc,
              tapply(lines,
                     com$membership,
                     function(i){
                      st_multilinestring(lines[i])}))
```

Plotting the two features:

```
> plot(mlines,col=c("red","blue"),lwd=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Tidyverse alternative:

```r
library("dplyr")  

com = components(graph.adjlist(st_touches(lines)))

# generate a simple features collection and add the group number
lines = st_sf(geometry = lines)
lines$group = com$membership 

# summarise by group
multi_lines = lines |> group_by(group) |>
  summarise()

multi_lines
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 5 ymax: 3
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   group                                                 geometry
#>   <dbl>                                        <MULTILINESTRING>
#> 1     1 ((0 0, 0.5 0.7), (0.5 0.7, 1 1), (2 0, 1 1), (1 1, 1 3))
#> 2     2                                 ((3 2, 4 2), (3 2, 5 3))

plot(multi_lines$geometry, col = multi_lines$group)
```

[image]

Although it seems that aggregate would also be a possibility: aggregate(lines, by = list(lines$group), FUN = unique)

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>